# why I got None in my function

Tags: python, dictionary

My code are the followings:

```
def hello(msg):
    return print(msg)


def hi(msg):
    t = 'this is a test time'
    return print(t + msg)


data = {0: hello, 1: hi}
for i in range(2):
    x = data.get(i)
    print(x('hello world '+str(i)))
```

However the output is:

```
hello world 0
None
this is a test timehello world 1
None
```

Question is why I got two `None`?

Comment: `print` returns `None`, so your `hi` and `hello` functions will return `None`

Comment: Either `hello` and `hi` should just return the absolute string instead of printing it. Or just replace `print(x('hello..` with `x('hello...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `None` because the print statement does not return a value, it prints a value to the console.

```
>>> a = print("Hi")
Hi
>>> print(a)
None
```

If you are wanting to add the strings together:

```
def hello(msg):
    return msg

def hi(msg):
    t = 'this is a test time'
    return t + msg

data = [hello, hi]
for i, func in enumerate(data):
    print(func('hello world ' + str(i)))
```

If you are wanting to randomise the ouput of the function, look into the [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice) function.